# Remove Line Chart values which is on the line on Chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I've created a line chart by using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I need to remove data points values (Which is on the line). Is there any accessible parameter to disable this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: *Charts* is open source, go to the correspondingfile.swift and comment the code that labels the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *setDrawValues* function. It enables/disables drawing values.

```
 let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
 data.setDrawValues(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove dots too:

```
let set = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "Y")
set.drawValuesEnabled = false
set.drawCirclesEnabled = false
```